# How can I get the IP of the talos vm on PROXMOX

Tags: ip, kubernetes, proxmox, terraform, talos

I want to create a K8s cluster with Talos VMs using Terraform's Talos and Proxmox providers. However, even when the qemu agent is enabled on the Proxmox level, it does not work because Talos does not have an image with the qemu agent preinstalled. As I can't get the IP address, I can render the Talos configuration file to connect to the nodes for configuration.

I have trouble understanding how [this](https://github.com/crisobal/qemu-guest-agent-talos/blob/main/Readme.md) solves that problem if it does.